# Is the set of vectors $(1, 0), (i, 0)$ a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, linear-independence

I've encountered a problem with two approaches, leading to contradictory results.

**Approach 1:**

Utilizing the definition of [linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20vector,said%20to%20be%20linearly%20dependent.), consider the equation $c_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} i \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. This simplifies to $(c_1 + c_2i, 0) = (0, 0)$, implying $c_1 + c_2i = 0$. Solving yields $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, indicating that these vectors are linearly independent.

**Approach 2:**

Consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = 0$. The rank of $A$ is less than two due to the second row being zero. $\text{rank}(A) < 2$ implies that there will be infinite solutions for $c_1, c_2$ other than the trivial one. Therefore, they are linearly dependent.

Which of these approaches is correct?

Comment: What does $\Bbb C^2(\Bbb R)$ mean? When you say "solving yields" ... why is $c_1=-i$, $c_2=1$ not a solution? Perhaps your odd notation signifies that we're considering $\Bbb C^2$ as a vector space *over* $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, I was using this notation - A vector space $V$ over a field $F$, denoted $V(F)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors are linearly independent. Your first approach is correct.

The second approach doesn't work because the 'infinite amount of solutions' will never be real unless it is the trivial solution $(c_1,c_2) = (0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extreme ambiguity in the question: do you mean linearly independent over $\mathbb R$? Or... over $\mathbb C$? They are linearly *independent* over $\mathbb R$, but/and one is a *complex* scalar multiple of the other, so they are linearly *dependent* over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Clearly over $\Bbb{R}$ as they put the vector space as $\Bbb{C}^2(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: @soggycornflakes, ah, well, ok... if that's what that notation means. I'd not seen it before, and thought maybe it was a typo...

Comment: @soggycornflakes It was not clear to me, either. I've never seen anyone use this notation before, other than for ordered pairs of complex-valued functions on $\Bbb R$.